# Is there a way to determine what program is calling a sound randomly on my Mac?

Tags: macos, audio, security

I'm currently having an issue with my Mac running Mountain Lion making the "lockOpening.aif" and "lockClosing.aif" sounds apparently at random. I'm looking for a way to narrow down what program or setting is causing them to be played and what action is occurring when it happens. I've seen elsewhere that there was a program that could be used to determine what sound is being played when, and what program is calling the sound, does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I have noticed that 1Password makes lock noises when the screensaver turns on, but this might not be related to your issue. You might be able to use `lsof` to figure out what program is using those sound files.

Answer (score 3):

This would show aif files that are being opened:

```
sudo opensnoop | grep -F .aif
```

Or see if any application has those files inside its bundle:

```
find /Applications -name \*.aif
```